# what is alternative of for in in darjs?

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I am looking for the alternative of javascript `for in` in dart:js?

for example:

```
if('addEventListener' in event) {
event.addEventListener(change);
}
```

I used `is` operator, but it's throwing an error in Safari becouse addEventListener does not exist in event.

```dart
if(event.addEventListener is Function) {
event.addEventListener(change);
}
```

Comment: You say `for in` in the first sentence, but doesn't use `for` in the examples. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking whether an object supports a specific method is not something you do in Dart. You should check that the object implements an interface which has that method.

In this example, you probably need:

```
if (event is EventTarget) {
  event.addEventListener("change", change);
}
```

If you think that the object might support the function, but you don't actually know which interface it gets the function from, then you can do what you try here, using a dynamic lookup, but you need to catch the error you get if the function isn't there.

```
dynamic e = event;  // if it isn't dynamic already.
Object addEventListener;
try {
  addEventListener = e.addEventListener;
} on Error {
  // ignore.
}
if (addEventListener is Function) {
  addEventListener(...);
}
```

Comment: is there any other way to check the property is exists or not?

Comment: Only reflection using `dart:mirrors`. That's not supported on the web, so not something that you can use with JS interop. If the object in question is a *JavaScript* object, not a Dart object, then you may be able to use JS interop directly, but you shouldn't do that to a Dart object.